# Bundler (or Ruby) mangling require paths

Tags: ruby, bundler

About 50% of the time, when I run `bundle` (or `bundle exec foo`) I get an error like the following:

```
> bundle
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/?y (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

To me it smells like memory corruption in the construction of the require path but I don't know why this would happen only when using Bundler and not with vanilla Ruby. I'm aware that Bundler patches `Kernel.require` but the bug (as per the trace above) appears to happen before the path gets handed to that method.

Versions of software I have:

```
> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
> gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.2.3)
```

I don't have rvm/rbenv/etc installed and there are only two rubies on the box, the homebrew installed one and the system one.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. Doing `gem install bundler --pre` fixed it for me.